# SVGKit performance and should it be preferred over PNG?

Tags: ios, swift, svg, vector, svgkit

I have been looking at SVGKit and I am finding conflicting ideas. Some say it's slower than PNG and others saying it is fast.

I was hoping to get a recommendation and which route I should take. When I am exporting my vector graphics to PNG for display, would it not make sense to use an SVG instead ?

Of course this gives the added value that it remains a vector.

Or is it still recommended in exporting everything to a PNG ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider the middle-way introduced in Xcode 7. Here you add your assets to the project as vector images (PDF) and at build-time Xcode automatically generates the PNGs in all needed sizes (1x, 2x, 3x).

Personally, I only use SVGs when necessary, like if I need to be able to change the color of the (parts of the) image. I believe there can be a performance hit when resizing vector images at run-time, although Android uses vectors as default, so it might be insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is most resource intensive and can be used if you need to display something that can be zoomed in and out while PNG should be preferred for most UI graphics (logos, icons, etc.), as it is crisp yet remains lightweight and fast to display so there is no way to compare SVG with PNG in term of Performance.
if you are going after a Crystal clear images you can use pdf based graphics, which are supported by Xcode Using [Vector Images in Xcode](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/)

if you still need to implement SVGKit i always suggest using some tools (like `SVGCleaner`) to clean and simplify SVG in order to enhance performance.